# combine Application.properties files when testing

Tags: java, spring, gradle

I would like to know how can I append the content of all my Application.resources files into a single one when running the tests for my application?

Every time I run the tests, some configuration must be added from `src/resources/Application.properties` file to `test/resource/Application.properties` file.

How can I obtain this?

I am using Spring and Gradle

Comment: First I assume you mean `src/main/resources` and `src/test/resources` instead what you have here. I strongly suggest using a differently named file for testing, that way it is quite easy loading both files and have the one for test extend or override the defaults in the `application.properties`. The test one could be named `application-test.properties`. You can also try to  load `class path*:/application.properties` this might load both files but ordering could be off.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done e.g. in the following way (there's a need to append main resources content to test resources file, keep old test resources for test execution, then swap the files):

```
apply plugin: 'java'

test {
   doFirst {
      def testRes = project.file('src/test/resources/test.resources')
      def mainRes = project.file('src/main/resources/main.resources')
      project.copy {
         from 'src/test/resources'
         into 'src/test/resources'
         include('test.resources')
         rename {
            'test.resources.old'
         }
      }
      testRes << '\n'
      testRes << mainRes.text

      logger.lifecycle('\nmain.resources text: ')
      logger.lifecycle(mainRes.text)
      logger.lifecycle('\ntest.resources text: ')
      logger.lifecycle(testRes.text)
      logger.lifecycle('\ntest.resources.old text: ')
      logger.lifecycle(project.file('src/test/resources/test.resources.old').text)
   }

   doLast {
      def testOldRes = project.file('src/test/resources/test.resources.old')
      testOldRes.renameTo(project.file('src/test/resources/test.resources'))

      logger.lifecycle('\nmain.resources text: ')
      logger.lifecycle(project.file('src/main/resources/main.resources').text)
      logger.lifecycle('\ntest.resources text: ')
      logger.lifecycle(project.file('src/test/resources/test.resources').text)
      logger.lifecycle("\ntest.resources.old exists: ${project.file('src/test/resources/test.resources.old').exists()}")
   }
}
```

Runnable demo can be found [here](https://github.com/Opalo/stackoverflow/tree/master/28781787).

Comment: @tzortzik, did you find the solution useful? If so add points please.

Answer (score 0):

In Spring you can import the data from existing resources. So basically, you need to create a Spring context file for your testing module and use the following tag to import the content of Application.properties from src/resources.

```
<import resource="src/resources/*.properties"/>
```

Comment: Where should I put this? I don't have an XML configuration file

Comment: This should be added in test/META-INF/context.xml. This will be Spring context XML for your testing. If it doesn't exists, then create one.